# Set input to read only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to build a grade book web app. I wanted to be able to edit the table cells to input grades, but I can't set it to readonly. What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing the code in the save button, but nothing works. I cant seem to get the input tags for some reason.Am I missing something? Is there another way to try to set the cells to readOnly? I tried getting the td tags, but that didn't work.

```js
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

var r = 0;
var c = 1;

function addRow() {
  //insert a row
  var row = myTable.insertRow(r);
  //insert cells into a row
  var cell = row.insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = "Students[i]";
  r++;
}

function addColumn() {
  //add new cell to each row
  var allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
    row2 = allRows[i];
    cell2 = allRows[i].insertCell(c);
    cell2.innerHTML = "Puff";
  }
}

function editCell() {
  var allCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var j = 0; j < allCells.length; j++) {
    //clear text, then put in input box
    allCells[j].innerHTML = "";
    var myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.type = "text";
    myInput.readOnly = false;
    allCells[j].appendChild(myInput);
  }
}

function saveData() {
  //turn all inputs into readOnly
  var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var k = 0; k < allInputs.length; k++) {
    allInputs[k].id = "inpoot";
    document.getElementById("inpoot").readOnly = true;
  }
  //document.getElementsByTagName("input").readOnly = true;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>

<button onClick="addRow()">Students</button>
<button onClick="addColumn()">Days</button>
<button onClick="editCell()">Edit</button>
<button onClick="savaData()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML IDs must be globally unique within a document. Since you're setting the ID to `inpoot` for each one, then the `getElementById` call is always going to be selecting the same element. Also, these elements are the `td`s, not the inputs themselves.

Try changing your save function thusly:

```
function saveData(){
  //turn all inputs into readOnly
  document.querySelectorAll("td > input").forEach(input => {
    input.readOnly = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I also spelled "saveData()" wrong on the button as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to try to set the cells to readOnly?

Use this :

JS :

```
var myInput = document.createElement("input");
myInput.classList.add("readOnly-input");
```

CSS :

```
.readOnly-input{ pointer-events: none; }
```

The user can't interact when pointer-events are set to none. Let me know if you need more explaination.